# Can't Link LRU Cache C++

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/lamerman/cpp-lru-cache) lru caching library in C++ in my `CMakeProject`. I went ahead and added it as a `add_subdirectory` and tried to `#include "lrucache.hpp"` as per the example but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the compilation or linker error you are seeing? Copy and paste that and it should be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like cpp-lru-cache has a well-written CMakeLists.txt. It does not use target based include directories by using `target_include_directories`, hence you will not automatically get the include path by linking library.

You will need to add the path to the include directory for cpu-lru-cache in your own project, e.g.:

```
target_include_directories(your_project PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/cpp-lru-cache/include)
```